# How Do I clean up a json string from multiple escape characters?

Tags: java, json

I have a string converted from a JSON-Object, which has multiple escape characters preceding each variable. 
I found a solution for removing one set of escape chars. how do I clean up and format my json string?

Here's how my string looks like:

> {"formFactor":"{\"form_factor_type\":\"SOMETHING\",\"payment_card\":\"{\\"SOMETHING\\":\\"NOTPRESENT\\",\\"card_holder_present\\":\\"NOTPRESENT\\",\\"UUID\\":\\"SOMETHING\\",\\"instrument_id\\":\\"SOMETHING\\",\\"signature_id\\":\\"SOMETHING\\"}\"}","txnCharacteristicsAmt":"[\"{\\"amount\\":\\"{\\\\"amount\\\\":\\\\"00\\\\",\\\\"code\\\\":\\\\"USD\\\\"}\\",\\"type\\":\\"CASH_OVER\\"}\"]","pmtCardInfo":"{\"card_present\":\"PRESENT\",\"card_holder_present\":\"PRESENT\",\"UUID\":\"SOMETHING\",\"instrument_id\":\"SOMETHING\"}","terminalInfo":"{\"cardholder_authentication_capability_used\":\"SIGNATURE\",\"pin_entry_capability\":\"UNKNOWN\",\"operating_environment\":\"ADMINISTRATIVE_TERMINAL\",\"terminal_id\":\"SOMETHING\",\"pan_entry_mode\":\"FULL_MAGNETIC_STRIPE\",\"card_data_entry_capability\":\"UNKNOWN\",\"pos_condition_code\":\"UNSPECIFIED\",\"cardholder_authentication_capability\":\"UNKNOWN\",\"pos_entry_mode\":\"FULL_MAGNETIC_STRIPE\",\"card_data_entry_capability_used\":\"UNKNOWN\"}","is_dyson_present":"SOMETHING","productInfo":"{\"tenant\":\"SOMETHING\",\"integration\":\"SOMETHING\",\"product_name\":\"SOMETHING\",\"tokenized_value_type\":\"SOMETHING\"}","cashOverAmount":"SOMETHING","counterPrtyAccNum":"SOMETHING","merchantDetails":"{\"merchant_address\":\"{\\"state\\":\\"SOMETHING\\",\\"address1\\":\\"SOMETHING\\",\\"city\\":\\"SOMETHING\\",\\"iso_country\\":\\"US\\"}\",\"merchant_category_code\":\"SOMETHING\",\"merchant_name\":\"SOMETHING\",\"issuer_list\":\"[\\"SOMETHING\\"]\",\"external_merchant_id\":\"SOMETHING\",\"acquiring_institution_country_code\":\"US\"}}

Comment: can you please make a short String so we can understand?

Answer (score 4):

Whoever generated that string really *messed up*. Badly!!

Each nested object was independently converted to JSON text, and that text was then assigned as a string value, rather than converting the entire object hierarchy as a single JSON structure.

They then encoded the nested strings *incorrectly*, resulting in bad JSON. Obviously they didn't use a good JSON library.

The correct solution is to fix the code that generated that string.

Below is your string formatted for human readability. The problem is that the root object starts with a `formFactor` field. Its value is an object, but rather than having the object as the field value, the object was converted to JSON text, and the `formFactor` field has the text as its value. This is repeated for the second field (`payment_card`), but the escaping is **wrong**:

```
"formFactor":"{
    \"form_factor_type\":\"SOMETHING\",
    \"payment_card\":\"{
        \\"SOMETHING\\":\\"NOTPRESENT\\",
        \\"card_holder_present\\":\\"NOTPRESENT\\",
        \\"UUID\\":\\"SOMETHING\\",
        \\"instrument_id\\":\\"SOMETHING\\",
        \\"signature_id\\":\\"SOMETHING\\"
    }\"
}"
```

The double-nested object's JSON text is incorrectly encoded. To see that, let's start from the inside. The `payment_card` object is:

```
{
    "SOMETHING": "NOTPRESENT",
    "card_holder_present": "NOTPRESENT",
    "UUID": "SOMETHING",
    "instrument_id": "SOMETHING",
    "signature_id": "SOMETHING"
}
```

When that text is then encoded as a JSON string for the `formFactor` object, all the quotes (`"`) are escaped:

```
{
    "form_factor_type": "SOMETHING",
    "payment_card": "{
        \"SOMETHING\": \"NOTPRESENT\",
        \"card_holder_present\": \"NOTPRESENT\",
        \"UUID\": \"SOMETHING\",
        \"instrument_id\": \"SOMETHING\",
        \"signature_id\": \"SOMETHING\"
    }"
}
```

When that text is then encoded (again!) as a JSON string for the `formFactor` field of the root object, all the backslashes (`\`) and quotes (`"`) are escaped:

```
"formFactor": "{
    \"form_factor_type\": \"SOMETHING\",
    \"payment_card\": \"{
        \\\"SOMETHING\\\": \\\"NOTPRESENT\\\",
        \\\"card_holder_present\\\": \\\"NOTPRESENT\\\",
        \\\"UUID\\\": \\\"SOMETHING\\\",
        \\\"instrument_id\\\": \\\"SOMETHING\\\",
        \\\"signature_id\\\": \\\"SOMETHING\\\"
    }\"
}"
```

But as you can see, that is not what happened. The number of backslashes (`\`) are wrong in your string, i.e. your string is **corrupt**.

***Fix the code that generated the string.*** Either by correctly escaping the multi-nested strings, *or* by not independently converting nested objects to JSON text. I'd suggest the second option, i.e. the above should just be:

```
"formFactor": {
    "form_factor_type": "SOMETHING",
    "payment_card": {
        "SOMETHING": "NOTPRESENT",
        "card_holder_present": "NOTPRESENT",
        "UUID": "SOMETHING",
        "instrument_id": "SOMETHING",
        "signature_id": "SOMETHING"
    }
}
```

#### Full formatted string

```
{
    "formFactor":"{
        \"form_factor_type\":\"SOMETHING\",
        \"payment_card\":\"{
            \\"SOMETHING\\":\\"NOTPRESENT\\",
            \\"card_holder_present\\":\\"NOTPRESENT\\",
            \\"UUID\\":\\"SOMETHING\\",
            \\"instrument_id\\":\\"SOMETHING\\",
            \\"signature_id\\":\\"SOMETHING\\"
        }\"
    }",
    "txnCharacteristicsAmt":"[
        \"{
            \\"amount\\":\\"{
                \\\\"amount\\\\":\\\\"00\\\\",
                \\\\"code\\\\":\\\\"USD\\\\"
            }\\",
            \\"type\\":\\"CASH_OVER\\"
        }\"
    ]",
    "pmtCardInfo":"{
        \"card_present\":\"PRESENT\",
        \"card_holder_present\":\"PRESENT\",
        \"UUID\":\"SOMETHING\",
        \"instrument_id\":\"SOMETHING\"
    }",
    "terminalInfo":"{
        \"cardholder_authentication_capability_used\":\"SIGNATURE\",
        \"pin_entry_capability\":\"UNKNOWN\",
        \"operating_environment\":\"ADMINISTRATIVE_TERMINAL\",
        \"terminal_id\":\"SOMETHING\",
        \"pan_entry_mode\":\"FULL_MAGNETIC_STRIPE\",
        \"card_data_entry_capability\":\"UNKNOWN\",
        \"pos_condition_code\":\"UNSPECIFIED\",
        \"cardholder_authentication_capability\":\"UNKNOWN\",
        \"pos_entry_mode\":\"FULL_MAGNETIC_STRIPE\",
        \"card_data_entry_capability_used\":\"UNKNOWN\"
    }",
    "is_dyson_present":"SOMETHING",
    "productInfo":"{
        \"tenant\":\"SOMETHING\",
        \"integration\":\"SOMETHING\",
        \"product_name\":\"SOMETHING\",
        \"tokenized_value_type\":\"SOMETHING\"
    }",
    "cashOverAmount":"SOMETHING",
    "counterPrtyAccNum":"SOMETHING",
    "merchantDetails":"{
        \"merchant_address\":\"{
            \\"state\\":\\"SOMETHING\\",
            \\"address1\\":\\"SOMETHING\\",
            \\"city\\":\\"SOMETHING\\",
            \\"iso_country\\":\\"US\\"
        }\",
        \"merchant_category_code\":\"SOMETHING\",
        \"merchant_name\":\"SOMETHING\",
        \"issuer_list\":\"[
            \\"SOMETHING\\"
        ]\",
        \"external_merchant_id\":\"SOMETHING\",
        \"acquiring_institution_country_code\":\"US\"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was looking for a programmatic solution  to format the corrupt json string. Could you please help?

Comment: Sorry, no. You should fix the code that generated the string. Always better the fix the source. Trying to fix corrupted data is problematic, since some original information may be lost.

Comment: Thank you... That helped. What is the best Json library that I could use?

Comment: [**Questions asking us to recommend or find a** book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource **are off-topic for Stack Overflow** as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Search the web and make your own choice. It all depends on your requirements.